# NGINX burst + nodelay против большего лимита запросов

Tags: nginx

Привет Всем!

Из документации [NGINX](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html) 
"Если же избыточные запросы в пределах лимита всплесков задерживать не
требуется, то следует использовать параметр nodelay". То есть имея
"nodelay" запросы в пределах burst будут обработаны немедленно?

Тогда есть ли разница между:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s; limit_req
zone=one burst=5 nodelay;
```

И

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=6r/s; limit_req zone=one;
```

Благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Разница есть и значительная.

В документации написано не очень внятно, но в реальности `rate=6r/s` означает что после успешного запроса все остальные в течении ≈0.16 секунды будут отклонены, т.е. вы не можете отправить 6 запросов сразу и подождать секунду, вы должны отправлять их по одному с перерывом в одну шестую секунды.

`burst` же позволяет «занять» обработчик запроса из будущего (обработать редкие всплески). Но среднее количество обработанных запросов всё равно не будет превышать заданный `rate`.

В ваших примерах в первом случае вы можете мгновенно получить ответы на 6 запросов, но следующий успешный запрос будет только через секунду после первого. Во втором случае вы можете обрабатывать 6 запросов в секунду, но между каждым запросом должен быть перерыв в 1/6 секунды.

Comment: "все остальные в течении ≈0.16 секунды будут отклонены" -- откуда эта цифра 0.16? Откуда у вас это более внятное чем в документации представление, поделитесь ссылками если такие есть.

Comment: @MishaPolitaev В документации написано: _Ограничение обеспечивается с помощью метода "leaky bucket"._ Можете загуглить. А 0.16 это 1/6.

Comment: Я поставил эксперименты и заглянул в код.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Только в первом примере, по идее, следующий успешный запрос будет через секунду после _первого_, т.к. именно тогда второй запрос освобождает место в "ведре" для одного запроса и туда тут же можно поместить следующий запрос.

Comment: @Roman поправил

Comment: @AlexeyTen "...вы можете мгновенно получить ответы на 6 запросов, но следующий успешный запрос будет только через секунду после первого." -- следующий то есть 7 запрос?

Если бы в первом примере не было "nodelay" тогда мы бы задержали 6 запросов и обработали с промежутком 0.16 сек? А если бы не было "burst=5" то эти 5 были бы отклонены?

Comment: «следующий то есть 7 запрос» — нет, тот который придёт через секунду. Все остальные запросы в этом промежутке (хоть миллион) будут сразу отклонены.

Comment: Да, `nodelay` влияет только на время начала обработки запроса. Логика ограничения запросов не меняется.

Comment: Если нет `burst=5`, см. второй пример.

Comment: Время через которое обновляется окно обработки запросов вычисляется из rate? При rate=30r/m оно обновлялось бы каждый 2 секунды? При таком rate следующий обработанный запрос был бы через 2 секунды?

Comment: Когда rate=1r/s, а burst=5 и нет "nodelay". Допустим пришли 6 запросов, 1 прошёл, 5 другие стали в очередь (burst). Через секунду из очереди обработался один запрос и тут же пришел новый и стал в очередь, таким образом, если поток запросов не прекращается очередь будет всегда занята и обрабатываться со скоростью 1r/s. То есть скорость будет той же что и без burst - 1r/s если поток достаточно высок чтоб держать окно burst постоянно занятый.

Comment: Время через которое обновляется окно обработки запросов вычисляется из rate — Да. Это нам проще мыслить и писать в запросах в секунду, но реально это ограничение на один запрос в период t.

Comment: Именно так burst и работает.

Comment: Благодарю за объяснения!